# Seeking Javascript JSON minimizer to work with dynamodb

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have survey data which needs to work in two languages and will reside in a dynamodb table.  The stored objects will contain many categoricals and I would like to make the storage as efficient as possible and not in a specific language.

Given the foreign key array:
["Religious", "Atheist", "other"]

I want to decode the object
{yourfriendsare:[1,3]}

to be:
{yourfriendsare:["Religious", "Other"]}

It needs to encode & decode deeply nested keys/arrays.
I would just give it paths (with wildcards) to the categoricals and an en/decoding array or similar.

I couldn't find what I was looking for on github/NPM (probably not using the correct terms) so before I wrote an encoder/decoder I wanted to ask here if such a lib already exists.

Bonus points if it can minimize key names too.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: At that point you can just try to gzip compress the data - or do you want to query based on the 1 and 3 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using jsonata. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonata
It can filter JSON well and (using functions) transform nodes reasonably well.

It is not purpose built for what I wanted but it's close enough.